# Problem with this integral $\int \frac{x^2}{3}-\frac{2x^2 dx}{3(3x+2)}$

Tags: calculus, integration

$$\int \frac{x^2}{3}-\frac{2x^2 dx}{3(3x+2)}$$
$$\int \frac{x^2}{3} - \int \frac{2x^2 dx}{3(3x+2)}$$
$$\frac{1}{9}x^3 - \int \frac{2x^2 dx}{3(3x+2)}$$
$$\frac{1}{9}x^3 - \frac{2}{3}\int \frac{x^2 dx}{(3x+2)}$$

But I get stuck trying to do a substitution

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For $\displaystyle \int \dfrac{x^2}{3x+2}\,dx$, I like that you first tried $u$-sub.  That would have been my first guess too.  But since it didn't work, we instead analyze the structure of the integrand.  It looks like a polynomial over a polynomial, i.e., it is what we call a rational function.  Notice that the highest exponent in the numerator is larger than the highest exponent in the denominator.  When this happens (or when the two exponents are equal), you can try to rewrite the fraction using polynomial long division.  It would be hard to write all of the steps of that out, but if you've seen it before, you should get the following result when you do polynomial long division:

$\dfrac{x^2}{3x+2} = \frac{1}{3}x - \frac{2}{9} + \frac{4}{9} \frac{1}{3x+2}$

so we can replace the fraction in our integral with this simpler right hand side to get:

$\int \dfrac{x^2}{3x+2}\,dx = \int \frac{1}{3}x\,dx - \int \frac{2}{9}\,dx + \frac{4}{9} \int \frac{1}{3x+2}\,dx$

The first two integrals are easy, and you can get the third integral by doing $u$-sub with $u = 3x+2$.  Hope that helps!

Comment: Doing long division I get: $$\frac{1}{3}x + \frac{2x}{3(3x+2)}$$

Comment: Looks like you are on the right track!  But you can keep going another step with the division.  With long division, you stop when what you have left has a smaller exponent than the denominator.

Comment: I did it, with reminder: $-2x/3$, quotient:$1x/3$

Comment: When I do it, I get quotient $\frac{1}{3}x - \frac{2}{9}$ with remainder $\frac{4}{9}$.  Do you want to take a picture of your work?

Comment: I multiply by 1x/3 to get rid off the 3 and  get $x^2$

Comment: So I wasn't saying that your answer $\frac{1}{3}x + \dfrac{2x}{3(3x+2)}$ is wrong, but if you stop the long division here then you will need to integrate $\int \dfrac{2x}{3(3x+2)}\,dx$ which is still hard since $u$-sub doesn't work.  So instead we can do two rounds of polynomial long division on $\dfrac{x^2}{3x+2}$ to get $\dfrac{x^2}{3x+2} = \frac{1}{3}x - \frac{2}{9} + \dfrac{\frac{4}{9}}{3x+2}$$.  This is now much easier to integrate.  Does that make sense?

Comment: ok, thank you I would like to see a picture of your second round of long division

Comment: You're welcome!  The steps are included here: https://www.emathhelp.net/en/calculators/algebra-1/polynomial-long-division-calculator/?numer=x%5E2&denom=3x%2B2

Answer (score 2):

$$
\begin{aligned}
\frac{x^2}{3 x+2} & =\frac{1}{9}\left(\frac{\left(9 x^2-4\right)+4}{3 x+2}\right) \\
& =\frac{1}{9}\left(3 x-2+\frac{4}{3 x+2}\right)
\end{aligned}
$$